# SliverAppBar - FlexibleSpaceBar isn't fading out as I scroll up

Tags: android, ios, flutter

The `FlexibleSpaceBar` doesn't fade the `background` widget when scrolling up. Rather the opacity of the background (in my example the FlutterLogo) jumps from 100 to 0 opacity once the flexible space fully collapses. The default behaviour should be that the image gradually fades in/out as the flexible space expands/collapses. I have tested this on both Android and IOS.

[image: FlexibleSpaceBar no fade]

Here is my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            expandedHeight: 300.0,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: FlutterLogo(),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              childCount: 100,
              (context, index) => const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('something here'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this means but I tested my code on DartPad website and the animation works https://dartpad.dev/?id=31f558c9d6be34cd156a6ad72e136155

Comment: Exact same issue here...

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. What Flutter version are you using ? Please also provide a flutter doctor -v

Comment: I noticed too late that a bug has already been filed on GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128636